# Groovy - method starting with "is"

Tags: groovy

I found code in existing project and I don't know why it works. Class has a method with name starting with "is". I can call foo.isBar() and it simply does its job. But in mentioned code i saw using simple foo.bar, and it seems to also work. But i don't understand why. I have tested it in online groovy compiler and it still works, so it's not something specific to that project. Is it some feature of groovy language?

```
class Foo {
    boolean isBar() {
        return false
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo()
//this one works
println foo.isBar()
//but why this one also works?
println foo.bar
```

Google search did not help. I don't even know exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groove has [Properties](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties) feature that introduces special naming convention (mostly following [Java Beans specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)).

Properties can be defined without backing field:

> By convention, Groovy will recognize properties even if there is no backing field provided there are getters or setters that follow the Java Beans specification.

Example:

```
class PseudoProperties {
    // a pseudo property "name"
    void setName(String name) {}
    String getName() {}

    // a pseudo read-only property "age"
    int getAge() { 42 }

    // a pseudo write-only property "groovy"
    void setGroovy(boolean groovy) {  }
}
def p = new PseudoProperties()
p.name = 'Foo'                      
assert p.age == 42                  
p.groovy = true
```

> It is generally recommended that the first two letters of a property name are lowercase and for multi-word properties that camel case is used. In those cases, generated getters and setters will have a name formed by capitalizing the property name and adding a get or set prefix (or optionally "is" for a boolean getter). So, getLength would be a getter for a length property and setFirstName a setter for a firstName property. isEmpty might be the getter method name for a property named empty.

You can read more about naming convention in the [documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_property_naming_conventions)

Comment: groovy does NOT introduce any naming convention, JavaBean does

Comment: The naming convention is introduced as part of Properties feature and implements JavaBean specification (but there are some custom additions though). Feel free to edit the wording in the answer if you feel like you can improve it.